# Beyond compare hanging

Tags: beyondcompare

I have been using beyond compare for several years.  It is a pretty nice diff tool.

This morning it started hanging, even when launching it with no arguments:

```
bcompare
```

I uninstalled:

```
yum remove bcompare
```

Verified that it was uninstalled:

```
bcompare
<something like, not found in your path>
```

And reinstalled

```
yum install bcompare
```

And still get the same behaviour.

When I run `bcompare --help`, I get this:

```
bcompare --help
*** glibc detected *** /usr/bin/bcompare: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000030d6990 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x38e5a75e66]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x38e5a789b3]
/usr/bin/bcompare[0x531407]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-01326000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 932222                             /usr/lib64/beyondcompare/BCompare
01526000-023db000 rw-p 00f26000 fd:00 932222                             /usr/lib64/beyondcompare/BCompare
023db000-023f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
02e70000-030e8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3692e00000-3692f49000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 660161                         /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.7.6
3692f49000-3693148000 ---p 00149000 fd:00 660161                         /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.7.6
3693148000-3693151000 rw-p 00148000 fd:00 660161                         /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.7.6
3693151000-3693153000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3693200000-36933b8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 657621                         /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
36933b8000-36935b8000 ---p 001b8000 fd:00 657621                         /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
36935b8000-36935d3000 r--p 001b8000 fd:00 657621                         /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
36935d3000-36935df000 rw-p 001d3000 fd:00 657621                         /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
36935df000-36935e3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3693600000-3693662000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 657623                         /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
3693662000-3693861000 ---p 00062000 fd:00 657623                         /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
3693861000-3693865000 r--p 00061000 fd:00 657623                         /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
3693865000-369386c000 rw-p 00065000 fd:00 657623                         /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
3693e00000-3693ef5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 665094                         /usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so.4.6.2
3693ef5000-36940f5000 ---p 000f5000 fd:00 665094                         /usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so.4.6.2
36940f5000-36940fb000 rw-p 000f5000 fd:00 665094                         /usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so.4.6.2
3694200000-3694267000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 657696                         /usr/lib64/libgnomevfs-2.so.0.2400.2
3694267000-3694466000 ---p 00067000 fd:00 657696                         /usr/lib64/libgnomevfs-2.so.0.2400.2
3694466000-369446b000 rw-p 00066000 fd:00 657696                         /usr/lib64/libgnomevfs-2.so.0.2400.2
3694600000-3694859000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 660109                         /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4.6.2
3694859000-3694a58000 ---p 00259000 fd:00 660109                         /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4.6.2
3694a58000-3694a64000 rw-p 00258000 fd:00 660109                         /usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4.6.2
3694e00000-3694e15000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 698430                         /usr/lib64/libgnome-2.so.0.2800.0
3694e15000-3695015000 ---p 00015000 fd:00 698430                         /usr/lib64/libgnome-2.so.0.2800.0
3695015000-3695017000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 698430                         /usr/lib64/libgnome-2.so.0.2800.0
3695400000-3695de1000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 698418                         /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4.6.2
3695de1000-3695fe0000 ---p 009e1000 fd:00 698418                         /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4.6.2
3695fe0000-3696024000 rw-p 009e0000 fd:00 698418                         /usr/lib64/libQtGui.so.4.6.2
3696024000-3696028000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
38e5200000-38e5220000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2228246                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
38e541f000-38e5420000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 2228246                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
38e5420000-38e5421000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 2228246                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
38e5421000-38e5422000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
38e5600000-38e5683000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2228320                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
38e5683000-38e5882000 ---p 00083000 fd:00 2228320                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
38e5882000-38e5883000 r--p 00082000 fd:00 2228320                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
38e5883000-38e5884000 rw-p 00083000 fd:00 2228320                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
38e5a00000-38e5b8a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2228248                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
38e5b8a000-38e5d8a000 ---p 0018a000 fd:00 2228248                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
38e5d8a000-38e5d8e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 2228248                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
38e5d8e000-38e5d8f000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 2228248                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
38e5d8f000-38e5d94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
38e5e00000-38e5e17000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2228252                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
38e5e17000-38e6017000 ---p 00017000 fd:00 2228252                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
38e6017000-38e6018000 r--p 00017000 fd:00 2228252                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
38e6018000-38e6019000 rw-p 00018000 fd:00 2228252                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
38e6019000-38e601d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
38e6200000-38e6202000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2228270                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
38e6202000-38e6402000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 2228270                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
38e6402000-38e6403000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 2228270                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
38e6403000-38e6404000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 2228270                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
38e6a00000-38e6a07000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2228254                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
38e6a07000-38e6c06000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 2228254                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
38e6c06000-38e6c07000 r--p 00006000 fd:00 2228254                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
38e6c07000-38e6c08000 rw-p 00007000 fd:00 2228254                        /lib64/librt-2.12.so
38e7200000-38e721d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2228300                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
38e721d000-38e741c000 ---p 0001d000 fd:00 2228300                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
38e741c000-38e741d000 r--p 0001c000 fd:00 2228300                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
38e741d000-38e741e000 rw-p 0001d000 fd:00 2228300                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
38e741e000-38e741f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
38e7600000-38e7616000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2228292                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
38e7616000-38e7816000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 2228292                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so
38e7816000-38e7817000 r--p 00016000 fd:00 2228292                        /lib64/libresolv-2.12.so/usr/bin/bcompare: line 45: 16139 Aborted                 (core dumped) /bin/bash -c "exec -a $0 $EXEC $ARGS > /dev/null 2>&1" $0
```

Any ideas?

On `CentOS release 6.6 (Final)`.

Using bcompare 4.1.1:

```
rpm --query --all | grep compare
bcompare-4.1.1-20615.x86_64
```

Comment: Have you tried to ask on their [forum](http://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/)?

Comment: @ge0rdi - No but I forwarded a link to this question to their support email.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out there were multiple `bcompare` running silently (no UI open):

```
ps aux | grep bcompare
myUser 15052  0.0  0.0 106092  1196 ?        S    10:36   0:00 /bin/sh 
/usr/bin/bcompare
myUser 15065  0.0  0.0 106092  1200 ?        S    10:36   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/bcompare
myUser 31187  0.0  0.0 106092  1208 ?        S    Oct07   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/bcompare <someFile> <someOtherFile>
myUser 31198  0.0  0.1 100888 19488 ?        Sl   Oct07   0:00 /usr/bin/bcompare <someOtherOtherFile> <YetAnotherFile>
```

Closing these with `kill -9` resolved the problem.

*As a side note, thanks to the beyond compare support staff, in particular [Chris K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4871247/chris-kennedy)  for helping me look into this issue.  You guys are awesome.*